# Android (With Game Maker) : Error type 3 Error: Activity class

Tags: android, game-maker

I've been using Game Maker Studio and I have been running into a problem. I have been trying to figure out the reason for why this problem is occurring so with the people at YoYoGames can solve a problem. This problem only occurs when I run the game as Android so it has to be a Android specific issue.

I will start up the game with an Android Device connected to the laptop. What is supposed to happen is that the game is compiled and played on the tablet in its debug form. And that before my laptop reset would normally be the case with no issues.

However, I instead now gain these outputs 100% of the time.

**Compile Output**

```
device
"c:\Android\platform-tools\adb" install -r "C:\Users\User\AppData\Roaming\GameMaker-Studio\Android\com.yoyogames.runner.apk"

rm failed for /data/local/tmp/com.yoyogames.runner.apk, No such file or directory protocol failure
"c:\Android\platform-tools\adb" shell am start -a android.intent.action.MAIN -n com.yoyogames.runner/.RunnerActivity

Starting: Intent { act=android.intent.action.MAIN cmp=com.yoyogames.runner/.RunnerActivity } Error type 3 Error: Activity class {com.yoyogames.runner/com.yoyogames.runner.RunnerActivity} does not exist. Compile finished: 14:34:50
```

**Command Line Output**

```
--------- beginning of /dev/log/system
--------- beginning of /dev/log/main
W/GAV2    ( 1975): Thread[Thread-237,5,main]: dispatch call queued.  Need to call GAServiceManager.getInstance().initialize().
I/GAV2    ( 2978): Thread[GAThread,5,main]: No campaign data found.
D/AndroidRuntime( 3372):
D/AndroidRuntime( 3372): >>>>>> AndroidRuntime START com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit <<<<<<
D/AndroidRuntime( 3372): CheckJNI is OFF
D/AndroidRuntime( 3372): Calling main entry com.android.commands.am.Am
D/AndroidRuntime( 3372): Shutting down VM
```

Now, because it is Game Maker, I am not here for a solution. What I am here for is to find out what sort of issues could be causing this. Because before my laptop had to be reset, these issues have never occurred.

So what could be the cause of it in terms of Android development? Only by knowing possible causes could I have a chance of fixing this.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same error after renaming/refactoring. In Android Studio, what I did was add the `applicationId` property attribute to my build.gradle file, and set its value to the application package.

Answer (score 0):

Go to global Game Settings and make sure that the application name package does not have any capital letters and matches your SDK key name in preferences android.

Answer (score 0):

I had this same problem, with the same error message. But, in my case, my device was full of memory, so I deleted a lot of info (songs, videos) and never appears again, I can now export apps to my device.
Hope this helps!

Answer (score 0):

It works for me after removing the game folder in C:\Users\remy\Documents\GameMaker\Cache\

Answer (score 0):

Your problem happens to me whenever I have Bluestacks open in my computer. It seems that an emulator messes with the GameMaker: Studio's compiler or something. When I close Bluestacks, everything comes back to normal.

Hope it helps!